# How to select multiple rows with max count when rows contain duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle

This is a bit of an odd issue. My data looks like below where there is an ID, a variant, and a count. I need to select the ID and variant which have the max count. The caveat is that only the first letter of the variant should be considered for the "max count" but the entire variant is required to be selected.

I need to group by variant using the first letter (a, b, etc.) and select the ID and variant that has the largest count.

I can't just select SUBSTR(variant, 1, 1) because I need the entire variant code (e.g. a1) in order to feed the data into another query.

From below I would need to get:

```
1, a2
1, b1
2, a1
2, b1 (or 2, b2) as they are the same count
```

| ID | Variant | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a1 | 3 |
| 1 | a2 | 5 |
| 1 | b1 | 3 |
| 2 | a1 | 5 |
| 2 | b1 | 4 |
| 2 | b2 | 4 |

The **variant** will always be 2 characters and the first character will be re-used across all IDs. I.e. even if there are a 100 different ID,  all of them will have some form of a*, b*, c*, etc where the * value represents distinct variants for the particular ID.

A single ID can contain an arbitrary number of variants as the * portion of the variant can be alphanumeric. The only common trait amount all variants are its a 2 character value with the first value being shared among all IDs (i.e. if ID1 contains a* ID2-IDX will contain a* as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the rows that have the maximum count per `id` and first letter of `variant`:

```
select id, variant, count
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, substr(variant, 1, 1) order by count desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

In Oracle, you can also use:

```
select id,
       max(id, substr(variant, 1, 1)) keep (dense_rank first order by count desc) as variant,
       max(count)
from t
group by id, substr(variant, 1, 1);
```

However, for many columns the first solution is simpler.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I need to look into partition by as I didn't realize it can be used to group rows when the column is not selected.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, avoids subquery...

```
SELECT ID, SUBSTRING(MAX(CONCAT(Count, Variant)), LENGTH(Count) + 1)
FROM Table
GROUP BY ID, SUBSTR(variant, 1, 1)
```